# Convert Two Associative Arrays into One Multidimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

I have 2 associative arrays resulting from 2 queries in JSON format below:

```
{
  "competence": [
    {
      "id": "21",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    }
  ],
  "schedule": [
    {
      "id": "34",
      "parent_id": "21",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "id": "33",
      "parent_id": "21",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "id": "32",
      "parent_id": "11",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "parent_id": "26",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla"
    }
  ]
}
```

These 2 arrays above generated by this code:

```
<?php

$queryCompetence = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id`, `title`, `description`, `image` FROM `competence` ORDER BY `title` ASC");
$querySchedule = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id`, `id_competence`, `title`, `description`, `image` FROM `schedule` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC");

$competence = array();
$schedule = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryCompetence)) {
    $competence[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'description' => $row['description'],
        'image' => $row['image'],
    );
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySchedule)) {
    $schedule[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'parent_id' => $row['id_competence'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'description' => $row['description'],
        'image' => $row['image'],
    );
}

$response['competence'] = $competence;
$response['schedule'] = $schedule;

echo json_encode($response);
die();

?>
```

I need to make a multidimensional array in php that will output the JSON below:

```
{
  "competence": [
    {
      "id": "21",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "id": "34",
          "parent_id": "21",
          "title": "blabla",
          "description": "blabla",
          "image": "blabla"
        },
        {
          "id": "33",
          "parent_id": "21",
          "title": "blabla",
          "description": "blabla",
          "image": "blabla"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "id": "32",
          "parent_id": "11",
          "title": "blabla",
          "description": "blabla",
          "image": "blabla"
        },
        {
          "id": "33",
          "parent_id": "21",
          "title": "blabla",
          "description": "blabla",
          "image": "blabla"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "26",
      "title": "blabla",
      "description": "blabla",
      "image": "blabla",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "id": "31",
          "parent_id": "26",
          "title": "blabla",
          "description": "blabla",
          "image": "blabla"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I achieve this? I've been searching around on the net but seems like getting no luck.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you're not wanting to use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) and [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would index the competences by ID when looping over them, then simply adjust its array when looping over the schedules.

This way, you don't need to loop over anything twice:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryCompetence)) {
  // `$competence` is now indexed by ID
  $competence[$row['id']] = [
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'title' => $row['title'],
    'description' => $row['description'],
    'image' => $row['image'],
  ];
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySchedule)) {
  $schedule[$row['id']] = [
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'parent_id' => $row['id_competence'],
    'title' => $row['title'],
    'description' => $row['description'],
    'image' => $row['image'],
  ];
  // If the parent competence exists, add the schedule to it
  if (array_key_exists($row['id_competence'], $competence)) {
    $competence[$row['id_competence']]['schedule'][] = $schedule[$row['id']];
  }
}
```

Then, if you don't need/want the IDs as keys when `json_encode`-ing back, you can use `array_values`:

```
$response['competence'] = array_values($competence);
$response['schedule'] = array_values($schedule);
```

Comment: Pardon me, seems like I missed something on your code. How do I put schedule array inside competence array? What I see is that competence and schedule are seperated in two different response object. Thanks.

Comment: @ITDudes That line `$competence[$row['id_competence']]['schedule'][] = $schedule[$row['id']];` adds the schedule to the `'schedule'` subarray of the matching competence. So in the end, the `$competence` array should be what you're expecting. Therefore, if you don't need the schedules by themselves, simply encode/return `$response['competence']`.

Comment: Great. it works, the schedule array is inside the competence now. But inside the competence array itself created a new associative "id" object, it make all the result inside competence id instead of "competence" array. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: @ITDudes Did you use `array_values` on it as suggested at the end of the answer?

Comment: It works as I expected now. I forgot to use `array_values` you mentioned earlier. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to iterate over the `$schedule` array, inserting its values into `$competence` where the `id` value in `$competence` matches the `parent_id` value in `$schedule`:

```
foreach ($schedule as $s) {
    // find the parent_id in $competence
    if (($key = array_search($s['parent_id'], array_column($competence, 'id'))) !== false) {
        $competence[$key]['schedule'][] = $s;
    }
}
$response = array('competence' => $competence);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5MeH4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but @Jeto's answer does a better job. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: No worries - note that you could include the `if` block inside your `while` loop which fetches from `$querySchedule` so that you wouldn't need an extra `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work like charm.

```
    $a = [
    [
          "id"=> "21",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ],
        [
          "id"=> "11",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ],
        [
          "id"=> "26",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ]
    ];

    $b = [
        [ "id"=> "34",
          "parent_id"=> "21",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ],
        [
          "id"=> "33",
          "parent_id"=> "21",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ],
        [
          "id"=> "32",
          "parent_id"=> "11",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ],
       [
          "id"=> "31",
          "parent_id"=> "26",
          "title"=> "blabla",
          "description"=> "blabla",
          "image"=> "blabla"
        ]
    ];


    $final = [];

    foreach($a as $key => $val)
    {
        $final[$key] = $val;
        foreach($b as $key1 => $val1)
        {

            if($val['id'] == $val1['parent_id'])
            {
                $final[$key]['schedule'][$key1] = $val1;
            }
        }
    }

$t = [];
$t['competence'] = $final;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($t));
```